# How to chain triggers on multiple tables in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql, triggers

Is it possible to chain triggers on multiple tables?

Primary table : **Questions**

```
  id     int
```

Secondary table : **Answers**

```
  id          int
  id_parent   int
```

Additional tables

**AnswersVotes**

```
  id_answer   int
```

**AnswersViews**

```
  id_answer   int
```

I need to create chain of actions if I delete a row from table `questions`

Is it possible to create trigger on table `question` which would delete rows in `answers` and also add another trigger on table `answers` which would delete rows in `answersvotes` and also `answerviews`?

Or do I need to add all delete calls in first trigger?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it either way - either with a trigger on Questions that deletes from all three tables, or by individual triggers on Questions and Answers, where the Answer trigger gets fired by the deletion in Questions.  I would suggest it makes more sense to have the separate triggers, in case one answer is deleted from a question.

Or you can set up cascade deletion on the relationships.